# ¿Por qué el comportamiento de mi código Javascript?

Tags: javascript

Tengo un código Javascript con el que estoy tratando una tarea simple. Procedo a compartir los códigos HTML, CSS y JS, si me pudieran ayudar a indicar si hay algún error en los códigos. Deberia cambiar el fondo de color si doy click a claro, obviamente un color claro, lo mismo con el oscuro, pero no cambia nada, sea cual sea el botón que clickee.

```js
//gesturess.js
var app{
 inicio: function(){
  var botonClaro =  document.querySelector('#claro');
  var botonOscuro = document.querySelector('#oscuro');

  botonClaro.addEventListener('click',this.ponloClaro,false);
  botonOscuro.addEventListener('click',this.ponloOscuro,false);
 },

 ponloClaro: function(){
  document.body.className: 'claro';
 },
 ponloOscuro: function(){
  document.body.className: 'oscuro';
 },



};

app.inicio();
```

```css
//gestures.css
body{
 background-color: #8eadc5;
}
body.claro{
 background-color: #f3e1bd;
}
body.oscuro{
 background-color: #577a76;
}
button{
 background-color: #7fba67;
 color: #ffffff;
 border: none;
 width: 100%;
 padding: 30px;
 font-size: 1em;
 margin-top: 10px;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1, user-scalable=no, width=device-width">
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/gestures.css">

        <title>Prueba App</title>
    </head>
    <body>
       
        <script type="text/javascript" src="js/gestures.js"></script>

        <button id="claro">CLARO</button>
        <button id="oscuro">OSCURO</button>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: ¿Cuál es el error? ¿Cuál es el comportamiento deseado? Debes explicarte mejor para poder ayudarte.

Comment: @MauricioContreras he editado la pregunta

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Hay 3 errores en tu código javascript:

La linea 2:

```
var app{
```

Debe ser:

```
var app = {
```

La linea 12:

```
document.body.className: 'claro';
```

Debe ser:

```
document.body.className = 'claro';
```

La linea 15:

```
document.body.className: 'oscuro';
```

Debe ser:

```
document.body.className = 'oscuro';
```

Además, te recomendo mover el script jsto antes del `</body>`.

Al final tu código quedaría así:

```js
//gesturess.js
var app = {
    inicio: function(){
        var botonClaro =  document.querySelector('#claro');
        var botonOscuro = document.querySelector('#oscuro');

        botonClaro.addEventListener('click',this.ponloClaro,false);
        botonOscuro.addEventListener('click',this.ponloOscuro,false);
    },

    ponloClaro: function(){
        document.body.className = 'claro';
    },
    ponloOscuro: function(){
        document.body.className = 'oscuro';
    },
};

app.inicio();
```

```css
//gestures.css
body{
 background-color: #8eadc5;
}
body.claro{
 background-color: #f3e1bd;
}
body.oscuro{
 background-color: #577a76;
}
button{
 background-color: #7fba67;
 color: #ffffff;
 border: none;
 width: 100%;
 padding: 30px;
 font-size: 1em;
 margin-top: 10px;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1, user-scalable=no, width=device-width">
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/gestures.css">

        <title>Prueba App</title>
    </head>
    <body>

        <button id="claro">CLARO</button>
        <button id="oscuro">OSCURO</button>

        <script type="text/javascript" src="js/gestures.js"></script>
    </body>
</html>
```